# El footer no se queda abajo cuando agrego más contenido a la página

Tags: html, css

Por lo que estuve viendo el problema puede estar en que el body no ocupa todo el height de la página, trate de darle solución de esta manera (adjunto parte del código). Pero al agregarle mas contenido a la página el footer se vuelve a mover hacia arriba.

```
html,body{
  min-height: 245vh;
  position: relative;
} 

footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #87aeb6;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

[image: Acá se ve como se desplazó el footer al agregar más contenido]

Comment: Además, tienes razón, puede ser por el `body`, prueba darle un `height: 100%;` al `body`, saludos.

Comment: Ya pude solucionarlo, muchas gracias. Me quedo de esta manera:                                     
                                                                                                                    `html,body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}                                                                                                                     
  footer {
  background-color: #87aeb6;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-top: 2px solid #717a7c;
  width: 100%;
}`